# Java Servlet with other project references

Tags: java, servlets, reference, project

I have run into a serious problem when integrating my servlet with another java project( non servlet )

I have a Servet running on the web that has a project reference of another project A that returns me an updated field STATUS in project A.

Would it be possible of project A runs simultaneously that updates a STATUS, and the servlet will always returned the updated field?

Right now I am just getting the default value of the STATUS, and when STATUS updates, servlet doesn't get the updated value.

sample flow is like this... I deploy the servlet, I run the project A, 5 mins later project A updates the variable STATUS, a remote client will ask the servlet to get latest STATUS from project A.

From my error, I can not get the updated STATUS from servlet unless I run the project A from the servlet.

Thanks in advance for answers!

Comment: I am afraid you are not providing enough details for me, or anyone, to be able to give you an answer.

Comment: Do you need to initialize some code from "project A"? Take a look at `ServletContextListener`, but I'm not sure, what you really want to know.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, an IDE is not a runtime environment. It's a development environment. The JVM (part of JRE) is the runtime environment. The JVM has totally no notion of "project references". All the Java code it knows about are the classes which are in the runtime classpath.

Servlets usually runs in a servletcontainer which is a standalone runtime environment at its own. If you execute a plain vanilla Java client application (e.g. a JAR with a `main()` method), it will get executed in its own standalone runtime environment as well.

If you want to have both runtime environments to communicate with each other, you'll have to look for other ways than "referencing projects".  If you reference a project, its classes will be taken in the runtime classpath, but the instances of those classes will not be shared among runtime environments.

There are however several ways to share information between runtime environments. Reading/writing a shared file (easiest, but also most errorprone), accessing a shared SQL database, or just communicating by RMI, JMS or even HTTP. Which to choose depends on the sole functional requirement.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, is there any way I can run the application in the same runtime environment when the web servlet is deployed? I am using Glassfish

Comment: Depends on the sole functional requirement.